# Sentence connectors /Conjunctive adverbs

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

In the given examples:

He never invited anyone. On one occasion, somebody came.

Does "on one occasion" act as sentence connector here acting as conjunctive adverb?

He has a tight schedule. At 5 am, he starts his day.

Is "at 5 am" a sentence connector acting like conjunctive adverb?

Comment: No. "On one occasion" and "at 5am" are both preposition phrases functioning as temporal adjuncts. Note that the adjuncts can occur in end position, e.g. "He starts his day at 5pm".

Comment: Thanks Bill, indeed grateful for your prompt response. I often get confused in deciphering sentence connectors especially when the second sentence starts with preposition/infinitive phrase as some of them act as sentence connectors /Conjunctive adverbs as per various website. Can you please tell the method to distinguish when they act as sentence connectors and when as  adjuncts.Shall be obliged. Regards

Comment: We usually think of connectives as being words like "therefore", "moreover", "also", "similarly" "alternatively" etc. They serve to express the relation between the clause they introduce and what precedes. For example "Kim was the only one with a Ph.D. **Moreover**, she had considerable teaching experience" / "There's a good movie on at the the cinema. **Alternatively**, we could have a quiet evening at home".

Comment: Dear Bill, Thanks again. The depth of your understanding is praise worthy. The connective examples cited by you are clear as Conjunctive adverbs. However, when PP/infinitive Phrases are used as connectors,  Ex-He sings. In addition to this,  he also plays instruments. Can the PP'in addition to this' be considered adjunct besides being a connector/Conjunctive adverb here. Similarly, "He wants to be a doctor. To achieve  his goal, he is working very hard. Can 'To achieve his goal be called a connector/Conjunctive adverb modifying the entire clause"he is working very hard". Warm regards

Comment: Yes, "in addition" can link phrases and hence is a connective. But In your last example, "to achieve his goal" is not a connective but a purpose adjunct, a modifier in clause structure.

Comment: Thanks Bill,in the example if  'To achieve his goal' were to read as 'To achieve this goal'would it be a connector since it refers to preceding sentence. If yes, would it also be a purpose adjunct in addition to a Connector.

Comment: The fact that "this" is anaphoric to something mentioned previously in the discourse doesn't mean it's a connective. "To achieve this goal" still a purpose adjunct. But consider this sentence: "There had been a power failure, [ _**so** all the classes had to be cancelled_]. Here, "so" functions as a connective adjunct, where it marks reason or consequence, But it is just the word "so" that is a connective adjunct, not the whole bracketed clause.

Comment: The example 'so'given by you is a standard connector which doesn't pose any problem in figuring. Its only the types mentioned by me that poses difficulty in deciphering. In my two examples, you say that only 'in addition 'is a connector. Do you imply that the whole phrase before comma i. e 'in addition to this' doesn't qualify as Connector? What kind of infinitive phrase will qualify as Connectors besides standard ones like to sum up,  to begin with, to be precise etc.